# viewing kafka messages on topic when using avro

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

So i have Kafka set up and am produce messages on the topic which use Avro. I currently use Ui for Apache Kafka which has the registry for schema set up. Once i updated the Avro I can see the schema has been updated. Since the message format is binary I am unable to view the message on the UI.

Anyone know how its possible to do view messages being sent in Kafka when using Avro.

Thanks

Comment: This one says Avro works. So open a github issue, if it doesn't https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui#features

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what UI you're currently using, we cannot suggest how to see Avro using that one.

You simply need to use a [different tool](https://forum.confluent.io/t/3rd-party-gui-tools-for-apache-kafka/6004).

Or, use `kafka-avro-console-consumer`